# ASP Classic Performance Issue

Tags: html, performance, html-table, asp-classic

Recently I got involved with a project that has been having performance issues on loading more then 1000 values on screen at once, and at first I thought it could be the database that was taking too long to pull the values. So I checked my query on mysql and it only takes about .53 secs on average.

So then I was doing some research on what the problem is and I believe its when the data starts getting populated into the UI..

I have the following part of my code, would it have to do with using response.write instead of <%= %> that's causing this issue, or could it be something else?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Scans</title>
<link href="/css/jScrollPaneLg.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
<%
if goodBrowser then
%>
<link href="/css/counts.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<%
else
%>
<link href="/css/nonie/counts.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<%
end if
%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jScrollPane.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['num-html-asc']  = function(a,b) {
    var x = a.replace( /<.*?>/g, "" );
    var y = b.replace( /<.*?>/g, "" );
    x = parseFloat( x );
    y = parseFloat( y );
    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0));
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['num-html-desc'] = function(a,b) {
    var x = a.replace( /<.*?>/g, "" );
    var y = b.replace( /<.*?>/g, "" );
    x = parseFloat( x );
    y = parseFloat( y );
    return ((x < y) ?  1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').dataTable( {

        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "sScrollY": "460px",
        "aoColumns": [
                null,
                { "sType": 'num-html' },
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
            ]
    } );
} );
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
// this initialises the demo scollpanes on the page.
//$('#pane').jScrollPane({showArrows:true, scrollbarWidth:17, scrollbarMargin:17});
});
</script>
<script src="/scripts/stop-copy.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<style>
td.grn{
width:40px;
}
td.red13{
width:40px;
}
td.red{
width:40px;
}
td.grn13{
width:40px;
}
td.cell{
width:40px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body onmousedown="browser()" onkeydown="return checkCtrlIns(this)">
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td class="scans-cell" valign="top">
<%
'response.Write tmpRows(0)
tmpHd1 = split(tmpRows(0),"=")
hdVals = split(tmpHd1(1),":")
howManyCols = Ubound(hdVals)+1
Redim dstrVals(howManyCols-2,41)

For k = 0 to howManyCols-3
dstrVals(k,41) = 0
Next
'244
tblWidth = 244+((howManyCols-2)*41) '10col 563px
%>
<table id="myTable" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" align="left" style="position:relative; bottom:-3px; left:0px;">
<thead>
<tr>
<%
For i = 0 to Ubound(hdVals)
    if i = 0 then
        response.Write "<td class=""symbollng"" valign=""bottom"" style=""border-right:0px; border-left:0px;"">" & hdVals(i) & "</td>" & vbnewline
    elseif i = 1 then
        response.Write "<td class=""close-hd"" valign=""bottom"">" & hdVals(i) & "</td>" & vbnewline
    else
        dstrVals(i-2,0) = hdVals(i)
        response.Write "<td class=""col-hd-wd"" valign=""bottom"">" & hdVals(i) & "</td>" & vbnewline
    end if
Next
%>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<%
EO = "odd"
For i = 1 to Ubound(tmpRows)-1  
if EO = "odd" then
    response.Write "<tr class=""grey"">" & vbnewline
else
    response.Write "<tr>" & vbnewline
end if
tmpRowVals1 = split(tmpRows(i),"=")
tmpRowVals = split(tmpRowVals1(1),":")
For j = 0 to Ubound(tmpRowVals)
    if j = 0 then
        response.Write "<td class=""symbollng""><span title=""" & tmpRowVals(j) & """>" & tmpRowVals(j) & "</span></td>" & vbnewline
    elseif j = 1 then
        if trim(tmpRowVals(j)) = "" then
            response.Write "<td class=""close"">&nbsp;</td>" & vbnewline
        else
            response.Write "<td class=""close""><span title=""" & tmpRowVals(j) & """>" & tmpRowVals(j) & "</span></td>" & vbnewline
        end if
    else
        Call addToDistChart(j-2,tmpRowVals(j))
        gTime = hdVals(j)
        response.Write getCellColorWithClick(curlv(tmpRowVals(j)),tmpRowVals(0),gSec,gChar,gTime)
    end if
Next
response.Write "</tr>" & vbnewline
if EO = "odd" then
    EO = "even"
else
    EO = "odd"
end if
Next
%>
</tbody>
</table>

</td>
<td class="div-cell">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="dist-cell">
<div id="dist-header">
<h2 id="scanName">Indicator Distribution</h2>
</div>
<div id="dist-wrapper">
<div id="dist-content">
<div id="dist-sym">


<%
For i = 0 to howManyCols-3
if dstrVals(i,31) = "" AND dstrVals(i,32) = "" AND dstrVals(i,33) = "" AND dstrVals(i,34) = "" AND dstrVals(i,35) = "" AND dstrVals(i,36) = "" AND dstrVals(i,37) = "" AND dstrVals(i,38) = "" AND dstrVals(i,39) = "" AND dstrVals(i,40) = "" then
%>
<div id="dist-cell">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="results" align="left">
<tr>
<td colspan="30" class="dist-ttl"><h3><%=study%> | <%=addMinHd(dstrVals(i,0))%></h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,1)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,1)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,2)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,2)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,3)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,3)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,4)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,4)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,5)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,5)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,6)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,6)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,7)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,7)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,8)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,8)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,9)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,9)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,10)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,10)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,11)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,11)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,12)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,12)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,13)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,13)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,14)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,14)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,15)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,15)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,16)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,16)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,17)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,17)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,18)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,18)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,19)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,19)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,20)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,20)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,21)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,21)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,22)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,22)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,23)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,23)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,24)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,24)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,25)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,25)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,26)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,26)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,27)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,27)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,28)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,28)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,29)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,29)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,30)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,30)%>" align="left"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" class="res">1</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">2</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">3</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">4</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">5</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">6</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">7</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">8</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">9</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">10</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">11</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">12</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">12+</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">13</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">>13</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<%
else
%>
<div id="dist-cell">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="results" align="left">
<tr>
<td colspan="24" class="dist-ttl"><h3><%=study%> | <%=addMinHd(dstrVals(i,0))%></h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,1)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,1)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,2)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,2)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,3)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,3)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,4)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,4)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,5)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,5)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,6)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,6)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,7)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,7)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,8)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,8)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,9)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,9)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,10)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,10)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,11)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,11)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,12)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,12)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,13)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,13)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,14)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,14)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,31)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,31)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,32)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,32)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,33)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,33)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,34)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,34)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,35)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,35)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,36)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,36)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,37)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,37)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,38)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,38)%>" align="left"></div></td>
<td class="barrt" valign="bottom"><div class="grn-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,39)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,39)%>" align="right"></div></td>
<td class="barlt" valign="bottom"><div class="red-bar" style="height:<%=getPercInt(getCleanInt(dstrVals(i,40)),dstrVals(i,41))%>%;" title="<%=dstrVals(i,40)%>" align="left"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" class="res">1</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">2</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">3</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">4</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">5</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">6</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">7</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">IM 8</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">P 8</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">IM 9</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">P* 9</td>
<td colspan="2" class="res">P 9</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<%
end if
Next
%>


</div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<!--#include virtual="/inc/inc_functions.asp"-->
<%
Function addMinHd(strVar)
if isnumeric(strVar) then
    addMinHd = strVar & " Min"
else
    addMinHd = strVar
end if
End Function

Sub addToDistChart(col,val)
Select Case lcase(curlv(val))
    Case "1"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,1)) then
            dstrVals(col,1) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,1) = dstrVals(col,1) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,1)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "-1"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,2)) then
            dstrVals(col,2) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,2) = dstrVals(col,2) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,2)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "2"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,3)) then
            dstrVals(col,3) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,3) = dstrVals(col,3) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,3)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "-2"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,4)) then
            dstrVals(col,4) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,4) = dstrVals(col,4) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,4)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "3"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,5)) then
            dstrVals(col,5) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,5) = dstrVals(col,5) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,5)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "-3"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,6)) then
            dstrVals(col,6) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,6) = dstrVals(col,6) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,6)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "4"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,7)) then
            dstrVals(col,7) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,7) = dstrVals(col,7) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,7)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "-4"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,8)) then
            dstrVals(col,8) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,8) = dstrVals(col,8) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,8)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "5"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,9)) then
            dstrVals(col,9) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,9) = dstrVals(col,9) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,9)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "-5"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,10)) then
            dstrVals(col,10) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,10) = dstrVals(col,10) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,10)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "6"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,11)) then
            dstrVals(col,11) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,11) = dstrVals(col,11) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,11)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "-6"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,12)) then
            dstrVals(col,12) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,12) = dstrVals(col,12) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,12)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "7"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,13)) then
            dstrVals(col,13) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,13) = dstrVals(col,13) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,13)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "-7"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,14)) then
            dstrVals(col,14) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,14) = dstrVals(col,14) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,14)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "8"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,15)) then
            dstrVals(col,15) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,15) = dstrVals(col,15) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,15)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "-8"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,16)) then
            dstrVals(col,16) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,16) = dstrVals(col,16) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,16)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "9"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,17)) then
            dstrVals(col,17) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,17) = dstrVals(col,17) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,17)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "-9"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,18)) then
            dstrVals(col,18) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,18) = dstrVals(col,18) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,18)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "10"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,19)) then
            dstrVals(col,19) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,19) = dstrVals(col,19) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,19)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "-10"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,20)) then
            dstrVals(col,20) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,20) = dstrVals(col,20) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,20)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "11"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,21)) then
            dstrVals(col,21) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,21) = dstrVals(col,21) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,21)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "-11"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,22)) then
            dstrVals(col,22) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,22) = dstrVals(col,22) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,22)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "12"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,23)) then
            dstrVals(col,23) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,23) = dstrVals(col,23) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,23)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "-12"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,24)) then
            dstrVals(col,24) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,24) = dstrVals(col,24) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,24)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "12+"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,25)) then
            dstrVals(col,25) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,25) = dstrVals(col,25) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,25)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "-12+"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,26)) then
            dstrVals(col,26) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,26) = dstrVals(col,26) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,26)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "13"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,27)) then
            dstrVals(col,27) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,27) = dstrVals(col,27) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,27)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "-13"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,28)) then
            dstrVals(col,28) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,28) = dstrVals(col,28) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,28)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case ">13"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,29)) then
            dstrVals(col,29) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,29) = dstrVals(col,29) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,29)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "->13"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,30)) then
            dstrVals(col,30) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,30) = dstrVals(col,30) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,30)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "im 8"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,31)) then
            dstrVals(col,31) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,31) = dstrVals(col,31) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,31)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "-im 8"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,32)) then
            dstrVals(col,32) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,32) = dstrVals(col,32) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,32)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "p 8"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,33)) then
            dstrVals(col,33) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,33) = dstrVals(col,33) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,33)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "-p 8"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,34)) then
            dstrVals(col,34) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,34) = dstrVals(col,34) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,34)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "im 9"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,35)) then
            dstrVals(col,35) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,35) = dstrVals(col,35) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,35)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "-im 9"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,36)) then
            dstrVals(col,36) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,36) = dstrVals(col,36) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,36)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "p* 9"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,37)) then
            dstrVals(col,37) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,37) = dstrVals(col,37) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,37)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "-p* 9"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,38)) then
            dstrVals(col,38) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,38) = dstrVals(col,38) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,38)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "p 9"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,39)) then
            dstrVals(col,39) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,39) = dstrVals(col,39) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,39)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case "-p 9"
        if NOT Isnumeric(dstrVals(col,40)) then
            dstrVals(col,40) = 0
        end if
        dstrVals(col,40) = dstrVals(col,40) + 1
        tmpVal = dstrVals(col,40)
        if tmpVal > dstrVals(col,41) then
            dstrVals(col,41) = tmpVal
        end if
    Case else
        'was blank cell
End Select
End Sub
%>
```

Comment: This may help you http://www.webdevelopersjournal.com/articles/asp_performance.html also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972335.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For maximum performance use [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid), a jQuery plug-in that uses templates to render the table only showing the rows needed.

Example: http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example1-simple.html

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A few quick things...

1. Table renders slower especially if it is having a lot of data. http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t300070-are-tables-slow-in-rendering.html
2. Use YSlow and you will get some hints on how to tweak your page.
3. The js and other static files could be added in the end of the page rather than middle.

Comment: Ill take a look and see what results I can get from your tips tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

Without delving too deeply in your code example, use Response.Flush() within your loop to output your results immediately to the browser. Otherwise, you are waiting for all data to be processed before being rendered.